# Get all data from api and insert into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, api, dom

I have 7 cards in my html, with an image, title, description and source column. I'm trying to get the data from gnews api and then populate my cards with the data i get from the api. I'd like the data from the api to swap out my placeholder texts and image. But i'm only able to swap out the details in the first card in my HTML.

The JSON from the API look like this:

```
"articles": [
        {
            "title": "xxx xxx",
            "description": "xxx xxx xxx",
            "content": "xxx xxx xxx xxx... [1514 chars]",
            "url": "xxx xxx",
            "image": "xxx.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "xxx",
            "source": {
                "name": "xxx",
                "url": "xxx.com/"
            }
        }
    ]
```

I tried a forEach but it got only the first card

```js
   const title = document.querySelectorAll(".title"),
   image = document.querySelector(".image"),
   source = document.querySelector(".source"),
   url = document.querySelector(".url"); 
   
   .........
   .then(function(data){
   data.articles.forEach(article => {
            title.innerHTML = article.title;
            image.style.backgroundImage = article.image;
           source.innerHTML = article.source.name;
           url.setAttribute('href', article.url);
            url.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
          });
}


// And also i tried to target every card individually which worked but that means i would have
// to target all 7 html cards that i have which would be quite cumbersome and repetitive to write.
// Below is the code for the individual targetting..

           news.title = data.articles[0].title;
           news.image = data.articles[0].image;
           news.source = data.articles[0].source.name;
           news.url = data.articles[0].url;
           news.description = data.articles[0].description;
```

How can i write the code to be able to get data from all the articles JSON and to fill up all the other cards with different news concurrently??

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to the community.

It looks like you still have a great work to go.
Well, you must first think this one through: you have to iterate through all of the cards and all of the components, which is something you are not doing.

That would mean something like:

```
   .then(function(data){
   data.articles.forEach(article => {
            title.innerHTML = article.title;
            image.style.backgroundImage = article.image;
           source.innerHTML = article.source.name;
           url.setAttribute('href', article.url);
            url.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
          //some code to skip to another card
          });
```

Keep in mind that

```
   const title = document.querySelectorAll(".title"),
   image = document.querySelector(".image"),
   source = document.querySelector(".source"),
   url = document.querySelector(".url");
```

all of these are retrieving arrays of elements, since you have seven of them, right?
In your code you keep on pointing to image, title source and url, whith no indication of index. If that's the case, you are constantly updating the first.

Try to do this:

```
   .then(function(data){
   let x=0;
   data.articles.forEach(article => {
            title[x].innerHTML = article.title;
            image[x].style.backgroundImage = article.image;
           source[x].innerHTML = article.source.name;
           url[x].setAttribute('href', article.url);
            url[x].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
          x++
          });
```

It's not a perfect solution, though.

Take a look at [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) and read it carefully. Take a few time to do it - I did it! If you still don't got it, let me know!

Comment: thanks for the reply.The cards updates now thankfully but there an error in the console. `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined at news.js:26 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) at news.js:20` 

I console logged description, which i've declared in a const and it showed it was getting the details from 6 out of 7 cards, but showed undefined for the last card... **Kindly note** that all the 7 cards have a p tag with a class of description. What do you think might be the issue here?

Comment: sorry for the delay...have you checked that stuff[x] is not null?  When I say stuff[x] it may be title[x], image[x] or any of the other elements you are trying to change.